# Application Status Bar not working properly

Tags: ios, camera, statusbar, swiftycam

As you can see in this video
In starting only signals and battery percentage is visible with no time. But when I move  next controller it only shows the time. Before showing the Time it shows a red layer of touch return to AppName`. I am  using Swifty Cam library for Image and video recording

**Please check the link for the video:** [Video Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_oXuFLaA098Ncyjl6Bn6lrHRel9OnS44)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Linked video doesn't work for me

Comment: @vpoltave please download this video because this is .mov extension video

Comment: @ShamDass Use - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}
where you find its hiding

Comment: @ShamDass video is not able to see, Share your screenshot and code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have checked the Audio, Airplay, and picture in picture capability. Please make sure that Audio, Airplay, and picture in picture mode is unchecked.

Try this. This will work for you.

[image: Screenshot]